# how do I check if a column exists in cassandra table in java?

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-2.0, datastax-java-driver

I want to check if a column exists in cassandra table in java,and then perform an action if it exists.How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get table definition via [Metadata class](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.4/manual/metadata/).  Something like:

```
Column column = cluster.getMetadata().getKeyspace("ks-name")
   .getTable("table-name").getColumn("column-name");
if (column != null) {
   // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: This is best route, you can query schemas but the tables that hold that info change between versions often so let the driver handle that logic.

Answer (score 2):

Extending `@Alex ott` answers, If you already have the Resultset/Row after executing a query then you can check if the column already exists in a row by using this 
`row.getColumnDefinitions().getIndexOf(<columnName>)`. 
if the return index is non-negative then the column exists in that row.

```
int indx = row.getColumnDefinitions().getIndexOf(columnName);
if(indx > -1){
   // column-exists. 
}
```

.